# How to get a default iOS navigation back button

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, mono

How can I get the default back button on an iOS UINavigationController? I have the button being added in code, but I want the default style. Is there an Enum of System Images that contains the '<', or is there not really a way, and Ill have to design my own?

Heres the code to make the button:

```
controller.DetailViewController.NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem (new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Stop, (sender, args) => {
    controller.DetailViewController.NavigationController.PopViewController(true);
}), true);
```

Its written in C# using mono touch, and Xamarin.iOS, but I can work on porting Objective-c/Swift code if needed. Im just stuck at this point and can't seem to figure it out at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you push your view controller then you will get default back button with navigation bar. If you don't want to push to push viewController then you need to add it on storyBoard. For pushing the view controller you write the code as

```
Your_ViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Your_ViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```